# Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION 577. employee bonus.string_agg does not exist

Tags: mysql, string-agg

I use this code. but, it is giving me the error `string_agg` does not exist.

What to do?

[image]

[image]

```
select customer_id, budget, count(*) as no_of_product , string_agg(p.product_id) as list_of_product 
FROM customer_budget c
left join 
(SELECT * , sum(cost) over (order by cost) as r_cost FROM product) p
on c.budget>=p.r_cost 
group by customer_id, budget
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct: [`string_agg()` does not exist in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html). That isn't standard SQL, and it isn't part of MySQL. That [appears to be part of T-SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) (SQL Server).

I think the closest MySQL analog is [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat). In this case, I think you can just drop it in:

```sql
select customer_id
     , budget
     , count(*) as no_of_product
     , group_concat(p.product_id) as list_of_product -- here
from customer_budget c
left join 
(select *
      , sum(cost) over (order by cost) as r_cost
 from product
) p
on c.budget >= p.r_cost 
group by customer_id
       , budget
```